# Apache Camel sends ActiveMQ messages to ActiveMQ.DLQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

There is a middleware in between of two other softwares. In the middleware I'm routing `Apache ActiveMQ` messages by `Apache Camel`.
the first software uses middleware to send message to the 3rd software and the 3rd one reply the message to the first(using middleware).

```
               1stSoftware <<=>> Middleware <<=>> 3rdSoftware
```

**Problem:**

when with the first one I send message to the middleware, middleware sends that message directly to `ActiveMQ.DLQ` and the 3rd one can not consume it!(Interesting point is this: when I copy that message to the main queue with the `Admin panel of ActiveMQ`, software can consume it properly!)

**What's the problem?! It was working until I changed the Linux date!!!!!!!**

Middleware is like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MiddlewareDaemon {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MiddlewareDaemon middlewareDaemon = new MiddlewareDaemon();
        middlewareDaemon.boot();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception {
        main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        //?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0
        main.bind("activemq", activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616"));      //ToGet
        main.bind("activemq2", activeMQComponent("tcp://192.168.10.103:61616"));    //ToInOut
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

        System.out.println("Starting Camel(MiddlewareDaemon). Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }

    private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            intercept().to("log:Midlleware?level=INFO&showHeaders=true&showException=true&showCaughtException=true&showStackTrace=true");

            from("activemq:queue:Q.Midlleware")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                    Map<String, Object> header = null;
                    try {
                    Message in = exchange.getIn();
                    header = in.getHeaders();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Exception:", e);
                        header.put("Midlleware_Exception", e.getMessage() + " - " + e);
                    }
                }
            })
            .inOut("activemq2:queue:Q.Comp2")
        }
    }

}
```

And the 3rd software(Replier): (this is a daemon like above, i just copied the `RouteBuilder` part)

```
private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            intercept().to("log:Comp2?level=INFO&showHeaders=true&showException=true&showCaughtException=true&showStackTrace=true");

            from("activemq:queue:Q.Comp2")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                    Message in = exchange.getIn();
                    Map<String, Object> headers = null;
                    try {
                        headers = in.getHeaders();
                        in.setBody(ZipUtil.compress(/*somResults*/));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Exception", e);
                        in.setBody(ZipUtil.compress("[]"));
                        in.getHeaders().put("Comp2_Exception", e.getMessage() + " - " + e);
                    }
                }
            })
            ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you changed is the time on one of the servers, then this might well be the problem. 
For communications over MQ to work properly, it is essential that all involved host systems have their clock set in sync. In the case of ActiveMQ there is a default message time-to-live (30 seconds, I think) for response queues. If the responding system is more then 30 seconds in the future relative to the host running ActiveMQ, then ActiveMQ will immediately expire the message and move it to the DLQ.